# Typo3 8.7.x / Typoscript: Can't get data from rootpage, slide stops before rootpage

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I want to get some fields matching my where clause. I it's not matching, then it should look at the parent page and so on. The problem is, that the slide stops before my rootpage.

```
test = CONTENT
test {
    table = pages
    select {
      where = NOT tx_pagesaddfields_sliderimages=0
      pidInList = this
      orderBy = sorting
    }
    slide = -1
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
      field = title
      wrap = |<br />
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to get only one title upwards in the rootline or collect more of them?

Comment: Only one title.

Comment: Is your rootpage or any other parent page of the type "Folder"? This would stop the slide function.

Comment: No, no parent is a sysfolder, only type page and shortcut. I know that bug with the sysfolder, so I even moved my sysfolder above the rootpage for testing

Comment: can you specify your desired result?. trying to describe your current query: get **all pages** contained in current page which have a entry in the field `tx_pagesaddfields_sliderimages`. if there are no results in current page, try for parent, parent of parent, ... until pages from rootpage.render the title of these (pages)records.

Comment: My custom field "tx_pagesaddfields_sliderimages" holds images for a slider. When there are no sliderimages found at current page, then it should look at the parent page for sliderimages and so on until and including rootpage

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for the first image up the rootline?

declare your field as rootline field:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields'] .= ',tx_pagesaddfields_sliderimages'
```

access it in a apropiate way:

```
temp.image = IMAGE
temp.image {
    file {
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        import.data = levelfield:-1, tx_pagesaddfields_sliderimages, slide
        import.listNum = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but need the tx_pagesaddfields_slidertitle field of this page too

Comment: then you have a conceptual error. all your needed information should be in the record which is inserted in the page record. either you define your own record type (with image and title) or you use one field of the metadata for every file/image given by fal.

Comment: ah okay, I know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Now I've got a solution for my problem with a little workaround.

```
lib.slidertitle = CONTENT
lib.slidertitle {
  table = pages
  select {
    where = NOT tx_pagesaddfields_sliderimages=0
    pidInList = this
  }
  slide = -1

  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj {
    field = tx_pagesaddfields_slidertitle
    wrap = |
  }

  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject = CONTENT
  stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject {
    table = pages
    select {
      where = NOT tx_pagesaddfields_sliderimages=0
      pidInList = root
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        field < lib.slidertitle.renderObj.field
        wrap = |
    }
  }
}

lib.sliderimages < lib.slidertitle
lib.sliderimages.renderObj.field = tx_pagesaddfields_sliderimages
lib.sliderimages.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject.renderObj.field < lib.sliderimages.renderObj.field

lib.slidericon < lib.slidertitle
lib.slidericon.renderObj.field = tx_pagesaddfields_slidericon
lib.slidericon.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject.renderObj.field < lib.slidericon.renderObj.field
```

Comment: I still think that your base query (`CONTENT.select`) is faulty as you select all pages which have `pid = this`,  that are all subpages of current - and then you go up the rootline doing the same query on all levels. you start with all subpages of current, and then use all siblings of all pages in the rootline.

Comment: Hm okay, that could be right. But now I'm going a new way and fetch the data via my controller of my extension